# Trigger a Button Click on Enter

Tags: php, jquery, html

By This code if I press enter it returns an alert. But I want to make a code by which I can press A keyboard and it will redirect to a page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Trigger Button Click on Enter</h3>
<p>Press the "Enter" key inside the input field to trigger the button.</p>

<input id="myInput" value="Some text..">
<button id="myBtn" onclick="javascript:alert('Hello World!')">Button</button>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I customize it. Please Help

Comment: Change `document.getElementById("myBtn").click();` to `window.location = "http://google.com"`.

Comment: if (event.keyCode === 65) {
        location.href = "https://google.com";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be everything you need:

```
<h3>Trigger Button Click on Enter</h3>
<p>Press the "Enter" key inside the input field to trigger the button.</p>

<input id="myInput" value="Some text..">

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // a key, remove if for every key 
    // or use this to find your wanted keycode http://keycode.info/
    if (event.keyCode === 65) { 

       location.href = "https://google.com";
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he wants to use "a" not "enter key"

Comment: I have edited that in, but just in case he wants another key, read the comment

Answer (score 1):

use 65 for key "A"

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h3>Trigger Button Click on Enter</h3>
    <p>Press the "Enter" key inside the input field to trigger the button.</p>

    <input id="myInput" value="Some text..">
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="javascript:alert('Hello World!')">Button</button>

    <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 65) {
            //redirect to any page
        }
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```